# how to connect Django-Rest-Framework to Azure Cosmos DB(MongoDb)

Tags: django, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I used these configuration but it is not connecting to azure

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'djongo',
         'NAME': 'cloud_db', ---db name
           'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
'CLIENT': {
                 'host': 'db.documents.azure.com',
             'port': 443,
              'username': 'db',
              'password':master_key,
              'authSource': 'cloud_db',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
           },
           'LOGGING': {
               'version': 1,
                'loggers': {
                  'djongo': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'propagate': False,                        
                   }
                },
             },
         }
     }
```

I'm getting this error

```
[2022-02-16T22:28:54.401Z] Result: Failure
[2022-02-16T22:28:54.401Z] Exception: ImproperlyConfigured: 'djongo' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
[2022-02-16T22:28:54.401Z]     'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Can Anyone Please help me to solve this issue, please help me with the configuration?

I have:

**host**:https://db.documents.azure.com:443/

**master_key**:ACCOUNT_KEY

**database_id**:database id

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'djongo',
         'NAME': '',
           'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
'CLIENT': {
                 'host': '',
             'port':'',
              'username': '',
              'password':'',
              'authSource': '',
                'authMechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-1'
           },
           'LOGGING': {
               'version': 1,
                'loggers': {
                  'djongo': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'propagate': False,                        
                   }
                },
             },
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you provisioned a Cosmos DB SQL API account and are using the Django Mongo client to access it.

Your endpoint for a Mongo account in Cosmos should look like this...

```
https://myaccount.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:443/
```

What you have is this which is a SQL API endpoint.

```
https://db.documents.azure.com:443/
```

Create a new Mongo API account and then get that endpoint and keys to pass to your Django client.

Comment: I want for SQL API endpoint only please help with this configuration

Comment: You can't use a MongoDB client to access a SQL API endpoint. You need to use one of the Cosmos DB SDKs

Comment: I want to use SQL endpoint only do we have any configurations for that ?? @mark

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You have a SQL API account already. The endpoint is in the Azure Portal on the Overview page. There is a Python SDK you can use if you want to stick with Python. If you need something to help you get started go look at the samples or quickstarts in the docs. They are easy to follow